# Check if a value exists in a php array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array like the one below, how could i check if an value that came in from a query string existed in that array, without using loops etc.?

I tired using `in_array`, but that seems to return true even if the value weren't there.

I need to check if the value exists in the `alias` part.

[Codepad code of the same thing I posted below.](http://codepad.org/mHzSHxXj)

```
<?php
$categories = array (
    'CAT1' => array('alias' => 'mediterranean-cuisine', 'name' => 'Mediterranean Cuisine'),
    'CAT2' => array('alias' => 'asian-cuisine', 'name' => 'Asian Cuisine'),
    'CAT3' => array('alias' => 'greek-cuisine', 'name' => 'Green Cuisine')
);

$category = 'asian-cuisine';

if(in_array($category,$categories)) {
    echo 'A category with that name was not found! '.$category;
} else {
    echo 'A category was found '.$category;
}

echo '<br>';


$category = 'xxx-cuisine';

if(in_array($category,$categories)) {
    echo 'A category with that name was not found! '.$category;
} else {
    echo 'A category was found '.$category;
}
?>
```

Comment: `without using loops etc.` Regardless if you'd need loops or not: why this 'requirement'?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a loop to check for something in an array? A loop is one of the most basic / fundamental control structures in programming... also, `in_array()` uses a loop internally, if that matters

Comment: Maybe he just has a thing for recursion. You can't use a simple `foreach` if you have mutli-dimensional arrays anyways without multiple nested loops

Comment: @Machavity How *can't* you use a `foreach` on a multi-dimensional array? `foreach ($categories as $category => $data) { if ($data['alias'] === $_GET['whatever']) { ... } }`

Comment: this sounds like a code golf, let's use `array_filter`

Comment: You can, but how would you traverse an `n` dimensional array? If your data structure is fixed that's one thing, but recursion (which is what functions like `in_array` use) can traverse any array without resorting to nested loops

Comment: You do notice that you echo 'it IS found' when it is actually NOT found, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array and check if value exists like this

```
$categories = array (
    'CAT1' => array('alias' => 'mediterranean-cuisine', 'name' => 'Mediterranean Cuisine'),
    'CAT2' => array('alias' => 'asian-cuisine', 'name' => 'Asian Cuisine'),
    'CAT3' => array('alias' => 'greek-cuisine', 'name' => 'Green Cuisine')
);

$category = 'asian-cuisine';

$found = false;
foreach($categories as $cat) {
    if($cat['alias'] == $category) {
        echo 'A category was found '.$category;
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$found)  {
    echo 'A category with that name was not found! '.$category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a multi-dimensional array and the value you're looking for isn't set as a key, you're going to need to use a loop here. However, if you *really* want to avoid a loop, you could take a few approaches.

The first and probably most efficient would be to store the aliases you're looking for in another array but as the key of that array:

```
$aliases = array(
    'mediterranean-cuisine' => 1,
    'asian-cuisine' => 1,
    'greek-cuisine' => 1
);
```

Then you can use either [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine if the value you're looking for is there:

```
if (isset($aliases[$_GET['alias']])) {
    echo 'Found!';
}
```

Because arrays are hash-maps in PHP, this won't use an actual loop internally and should be more efficient than any loop-based approach.

An alternative to this could make use of an array callback / walking function such as [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
function alias_check($category) {
    return ($category['alias'] === $_GET['alias']);
}

$matches = array_filter($categories, 'alias_check');
if (count($matches) > 0) {
    echo 'Found!';
}
```

Internally, this *does* iterate over each element in your array so it technically doesn't avoid a loop; however, you won't have to write one yourself which is nice.

Though, the most straightforward and cleanest approach would be to use a simple loop:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category['alias'] === $_GET['alias']) {
        echo 'Found';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP >= 5.5.0 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the array of aliases.

```
$aliases = array_column($categories, 'alias');
```

You can then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$category = 'asian-cuisine';

if(in_array($category, $aliases)) {
    echo 'A category was found '.$category;
} else {
    echo 'A category with that name was not found! '.$category;
}

echo '<br>';


$category = 'xxx-cuisine';

if(in_array($category, $aliases)) {
    echo 'A category was found '.$category;
} else {
    echo 'A category with that name was not found! '.$category;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "Foreach" to navigate into an array :

```
<?php
$categories = array (
    'CAT1' => array('alias' => 'mediterranean-cuisine', 'name' => 'Mediterranean Cuisine'),
    'CAT2' => array('alias' => 'asian-cuisine', 'name' => 'Asian Cuisine'),
    'CAT3' => array('alias' => 'greek-cuisine', 'name' => 'Green Cuisine')
);

$category = 'asian-cuisine';

foreach($categories as $c => $k)
{
    if(in_array($category,$k))
        echo $category." founded in array ".$c."<br/>";
}
```

See more information about Foreach on the PHP manual => http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Edit : not fast enough =)