# Boolean with a for each loop

Tags: php

I'm failing from the past hour with a simple Boolean thing involving a for each loop. This is way it goes.

```
//this is in an include file 
$fetchData = True; // cannot be changed since most pages use it and it works fine 
since they dont use a for each loop there.

//main page
$categories = array (
        'CAT1' => array('alias' => 'mediterranean-cuisine', 'name' => 'Mediterranean Cuisine'),
        'CAT2' => array('alias' => 'asian-cuisine', 'name' => 'Asian Cuisine'),
        'CAT3' => array('alias' => 'greek-cuisine', 'name' => 'Green Cuisine')
    );

$category = 'asian-cuisine';

    foreach($categories as $alias) {
        if($alias['alias'] === $category) {
            $category = $alias['name'];
            break;
        } else {
            $fetchData = false;// a value was not found in alias
        }
    }

if($fetchData) {
    echo 'Ok to fetch data';
} else {
    echo 'Do not fetch data';
}
```

The whole idea is to check if a value exists in alias, and proceed if it does, or do nothing if it's not found. But the problem here is, it returns true for the 1st one, but if it's the rest, it always returns false. How do I get this right?

Above, `asian-cuisine` should be true, but I get `do not fetch data`. Can you help?

[Code](http://codepad.org/YMSGhtWG)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a value exists in a php array like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058514/check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-php-array-like-this)

Comment: Dude... you asked pretty much the same question an hour ago. Why not stick with that tread? If anything changes: you can edit your question if you'd like

Comment: This isn't about check if a value exists. It's the Boolean part.

Comment: Put the variable $categories before the foreach()-loop begins.

Comment: It's that way. I copied wrongly here.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's an extension to the same problem, and should be handled in your primary question. A problem can behold many factors

Comment: @Norman Yes, but your previous question has a lot of better answer than the one you picked, and that would not cause that boolean issue ...

Comment: @ClémentMalet Umm... which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working because if the first item in the loop fails this if condition, then your boolean gets set to false.

Then if a later item passes the condition, you break out of the loop, with your boolean still set to false.

Ideally you would start with the boolean set to false, and only set it to true if your condition passes. But you suggest this is not possible, so simply set it to true before you break:

```
foreach($categories as $alias) {
    if($alias['alias'] === $category) {
        $category = $alias['name'];
        $fetchData = true;//<--important
        break;
    } else {
        $fetchData = false;// a value was not found in alias
    }
}
```

Comment: `$fetchData = True` is in the include file above.

Comment: @Norman: But it stays false even if the alias exists. If you just turned it false.